# Правильное написание словосочетания

Tags: фразеология

"Сожитель её не работает, получает пенсию за выслугу лет. **Оба сожителя** по возможности подрабатывают, помогая жителям поселка в делах по хозяйству."
В этом тексте "оба сожителя" были поняты неоднозначно. Подразумевалось, что это он и она - сожитель и сожительница, а было понято, как два сожителя у одной сожительницы. Можно ли было так высказываться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Трудно себе представить, чтобы из текста, где это слово употреблено только в сочетаниях "её сожитель" (=человек, состоящий с ней в незарегистрированном браке) и "оба сожителя" (ровно два уже упомянутых человека), можно было понять, что людей больше двух. Разве что злонамеренно, из крючкотворства такое бывает. "Сожитель" в значении "сосед по дому" разве что пару веков назад бытовало. Только если текст юридически значимый, возможно, и нужно искать обходные пути (в делах об имущественных правах могут быть попытки трактовать это слово как "лицо, совместно проживающее" в квартире, выяснять, член семьи это или нет и т.п.). В любом случае, в тексте речь только о двух людях. Иначе следовало бы так написать:

Один её сожитель не работает... Оба её сожителя...

Comment: Спасибо! Я согласна с Вами на все сто процентов. Каждый, видимо, понимает в меру своей испорченности. Но дальше таких высказываний постараюсь избежать.

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли было так высказываться?

Можно. Но только в том случае, если бы другими это было бы понято однозначно. А коли возможны разные понимания...

Я бы написал примерно так: ***И она*** [лучше "она" заменить её именем]***, и её сожитель по возможности подрабатывают...***

Comment: Спасибо! Впредь буду осторожнее высказываться, а то можно и до суда дойти с заинтересованными лицами.

Answer (score 0):

В отношении количества сожителей изложить можно проще: "Сожитель её не работает, получает пенсию за выслугу лет; но оба по возможности подрабатывают". И разнесение "не работает - подрабатывают" в отдельные предложения тоже наводят тень на плетень там, где, должна быть ясность.